# IntelliJ IDEA 13 highlighting of SQL statement

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, highlighting

IntelliJ IDEA 13 includes new improvement **Statement highlighting** in Database Console:

[image]

How to change color of highlighting ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to go to: Setting -> Editor -> Colors  & Fonts -> General -> Injected language fragment -> Background

Comment: Please give me more exact instruction. Which of the options I must to change in SQL section ?

Comment: @DozortsevAnton Sorry - I've read your question one more time and just fixed my answer :)

Comment: @Anton Dozortsev, Setting -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> **Code ** -> Injected language fragment -> Background